# how to assign last row value into current cell from Hive sql?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have case-when from my SQL, it shows if price increases or decreases

```
 select
        price,
        lastPrice,
        case
          when price<lastPrice then "Decrease"
          when price>lastPrice then "Increase"
          else ???<last_status>???
          end status
 from ...
```

But if price is equal to lastPrice, I want to put last row status (increase or decrease) into status

I tried with lag function, seems not working. How could I put last row value into "else"

Comment: last row status is exactly what? I guess it's previous row, right? Ordered by what? To find previous row you need some column which determines the order of rows, like timestamp or date, etc

Comment: This is more complicated that it may look. Basically this requires a recursive query (so you can keep track of the last computed stats) - and I don't think that Hive supports that.

Comment: What about first row. I think, lag function will do if you consider the previous value for first row as zero and consider it as increment. Last value would be the lag value and you can compare.